# Javascript to only show preloader once in a session

Tags: javascript, caching, loader

At the moment my pre-loader appears when a user lands on the homepage which is fine, however I want to understand how I can make sure this only appears once per session so if you navigate back to the homepage it doesn't happen again, as currently, it happens whenever the homepage is loading.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
     const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
     loader.className += " hidden";
});
```

```css
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loader img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.loader.hidden {
  animation: fadeOut 1s;
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    <h1>PENSACOLA</h1>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use session storage

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
          if (!sessionStorage.viewed){
              const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
              loader.className += " hidden";
              sessionStorage.viewed = 1;
          }else{
            const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
            loader.style.display = "none";
          }
});
```

Explanation :
After the page loads, the `if` statement will check if sessionStorage isn't set to viewed (and by default, sessionStorage isn't set to viewed) after the statement is found true, your desired code will run. After running your code, with  `sessionStorage.viewed = 1;` will set the `sessionStorage.viewed` statement to true.

So, if you reload the page in the same session, the if statement will not run because we set  `sessionStorage.viewed` statement to true previous time.

The same thing will happen until you close the session.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation. I've added the following code, however now when I return to the homepage (in incognito and a normal tab), the loading page animation continues to run and doesn't fadeOut.

Comment: @LiamAtkins Thanks for sharing your experience. Will get back soon.

Comment: @LiamAtkins I ran the code myself but I don't see any problem. Whatever you do or wherever you navigate, if you are doing all your actiivity in a single tab then it should work.

Comment: Thanks Praneet, here's a link to my website. When you navigate back to the homepage the load screen appears a second time and doesn't fadeOut. (http://pensacola.co.uk/). Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have seen  the code. You have not implemented the suggestion. Try the code as I suggested above in the answer.(use `sessionStorage`).

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code (http://pensacola.co.uk/). Is it working for you now?

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake. I will update the code and then it should work.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the code. Try it. It should work.

Comment: That's great, thanks so much for your help. It's working nicely.